# Request that "possible duplicate" and "marked as duplicate" be changed to use "similar"

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions

I feel the term "similar"

```
"almost the same as someone or something else"
```

is more appropriate than "duplicate"

```
"exactly the same as something else : made as an exact copy of something else"
```

for when similar questions are asked.

Before you ask a question you search for what you want to ask. And before you post you are presented a list of questions that have similar words that the software thinks might be the same. So it is normally not the case that a duplicate question is being asked, and confusing to the poster to be told their question is a duplicate when they can see that it is not. It turns out there is something that could be used in place of "possible duplicate" as I just got it:

```
This question may already have an answer here:
```

Another good, and maybe best possibility is "references same subject matter" or "possibly references same subject matter". It appears that what the "duplication notifier/identifier" is actually referring to in most cases is the subject matter.

Comment: Disagree. Even though technically you are correct very few if any "duplicates" are actually duplicates according to the dictionary definition being merely "similar" is not sufficient to close a question.

Comment: The only way to combat duplication in such a large network is to re-structure it to provide a home, so to speak, for said content. "Duplications" don't need to be made publicly available all the time, they could only be shown on the right hand side under a title called "Similar Questions" and only be visible when you're viewing a question that has been marked as 'being similar' to any linked questions. This way there will be no trash, but the users still get their help, and the community still benefits from _similar_ posts (which are more often than not helpful).

Answer (score 1):

When I search in Google, Google embeds in the results a dictionary entry for the term "duplicate". The second definition:

> having two corresponding or identical parts.

It gives the example:

> "a duplicate application form"

This is what "duplicate" means here. When we say a question is duplicate of another we're saying that they have *enough parts* that correspond or are identical that it warrants marking them as duplicates.

Comment: Merriam Webster - correspond - to be similar or equal to something. The questions are virtually never equal. They are sometimes similar. What is really similar is the subject matter, and possibly the answers. [possible duplicate subject matter] or [duplicate subject matter]  would also be an improvement over [possible duplicate] and [question closed as duplicate].

Comment: I don't follow your comment. Are you disagreeing about the definition of correspond?

Comment: Sorry. I first read (past tense) you as continuing to harp on equality. At any rate, I don't think we need to refine that language.